# How do I connect to a neo4j embedded instance via bolt using the neo4j browser?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-bolt, neo4j-embedded

I've followed the instructions in [section 4.14 of the documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/tutorials-java-embedded/) but I can't figure out how to connect the neo4j browser to my embedded instance. Once the server is running, I open the browser via neo4j desktop and run `:server connect`. This prompts me for a host, username, and password. I'm not sure what to put for these values. I've tried many combinations of `localhost`, `localhost:7687`, and `bolt://localhost:7687` for the host, and I've tried username/password combinations such as neo4j/neo4j, neo4j as a username with a blank password, and a blank username and password. I've never set a username and password for the database. No matter what I try, I always get the following error:

```
ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use. WebSocket `readyState` is: 3
```

What are the proper values for host, username, and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out either `localhost:7687` or `bolt://localhost:7687` is fine, and username/password can both be empty. Interestingly enough, the way I was building my uber-jar with maven seemed to make the bolt dependency unavailable. I switched to [buck](https://buckbuild.com/) and the bolt connector seemed to start.